# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la ruta por defecto de una base de datos realm en Android?

Tags: android

El problema es que soy de Cuba y aqui la pagina oficial de realm esta bloqueada solo me queda stackoverflow para preguntar. Esto lo aprendi de un tutorial esta es la configuracion de mi realmDB que se ejecuta antes del MainActivity de mi apk. Alguien me puede ayudar...?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
  public static AtomicInteger BoardId = new AtomicInteger();
  public static AtomicInteger NoteID = new AtomicInteger();

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    setUpRealmConfig();

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    BoardId = getIdByTable(realm, Board.class);
    NoteID = getIdByTable(realm, Note.class);
    realm.close();
}

private void setUpRealmConfig()
{
    RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration
            .Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
}

private <T extends RealmObject> AtomicInteger getIdByTable(Realm realm, Class<T> anyClass)
{
    RealmResults<T> results = realm.where(anyClass).findAll();

    return (results.size() > 0) ? new AtomicInteger(results.max("id").intValue()) : new AtomicInteger();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm Configuration Builder permite configurar la [ruta](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/) de la carpeta . Por lo tanto, debería poder dirigirlo a la carpeta apropiada ejemplo la tarjeta SD.:

```
File folder = new File("/data/user/0/...");
RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(folder).build();
```

También puede verificar si fue configurado correctamente por:

```
realmConfig.getRealmFolder().getAbsolutePath()
```

También:

- constructor. **directorio()**
- constructor. **nombre()**

Ejemplo de los métodos a usar en tu clase de aplicación:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

    initializeRealm();
}

private void initializeRealm() {

    Realm.init(this);

    RealmConfiguration.Builder realmBuilder = new RealmConfiguration.Builder();
    realmBuilder.directory(new File(getRealmPath(this)));
    realmBuilder.name("realmDataBase.realm");

    RealmConfiguration config = realmBuilder.build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
}

public String getRealmPath(Context context) {

    String externalStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String packageName = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    return externalStorageDir + File.separator + "Android" + File.separator + "data" + File.separator + packageName + File.separator + "realm" + File.separator;
}
```

> Y puede probar esto: Realm.getDefaultInstance (). GetConfiguration (). GetRealmDirectory ()

Comment: Muchas gracias de mucha ayuda

Comment: @AlexRivas me alegra haber ayudado, Saludos.

Comment: pero en la clase que puse, esta se ejecuta antes de que empiece la ejecucion la apk como tal y no puedo darle los permisos para android 6.0 que hago??

Comment: me funciona el codigo que me diste pero para android 6.0 no... y no se como darle permisos a la clase que puse puesto que no es un activity y el requestPermission necesita como primer parametro un activity alguna sugerencia??